# 14.04 - How to automatically get sudo rights to objects on desktop

Tags: permissions, .desktop

When I FTP things from my Desktop PC onto my Ubuntu laptop's desktop, I don't have root priveleges for those files, so I need to remove it manually with sudo nautilus.

Is there any way to automatically give me permissions to files that are transferred onto my desktop?

Comment: Are you ftp'ing the files as root? if you ftp (or - better - scp or sftp) using the credentials of the account in question you should not have that issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using filezilla client

Comment: but what username do you use when opening the connection via filezilla?

Comment: I use the credentials of a filezilla account i created with r/w permissions

Answer (score 0):

After you have transferred the files on to your desktop you may use the command
`chown` 
to change ownership to yourself